# Which is the correct answer to "who is…?": "He is…" or "It is…"?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns, wh-questions, dummy-pronouns

I'd like to know how to begin the answer to the following question.

> Who is the actor that played an action hero in Speed, a cyber-criminal in The Matrix, a killing machine in John Wick, and who’s now featuring in a new video game that takes elements from all of these roles?

> **He is** / **It is** none other than Hollywood A-lister Keanu Reeves.

Also consider the followng

> Who's ringing the doorbell? **It** must be Peter.

Comment: Ah look, it is none other than that famous actor [coming out the door]. He is Keanu Reeves. Get it?

Comment: "It is none other than..." works fine. An answer, say in Yahoo Questions, or Quora, or somewhere doesn't have to be a full sentence -- you could just write "Keanu Reeves".

Comment: Also, the guy used to play bass in a band called *Becky*.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "It" for both sentences.

We often use pronouns like "it", "this" or "that" when responding to "who" or "which" questions because we want a *dummy pronoun* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun

- "Who is the lady on the phone?" "It's my mom" -> [The lady on the phone] is my mom
- "Who is over there?" "That is my teacher" -> [The person over there] is my teacher
- "Who is the manager at the desk?" "Its Susan" -> [The manager at the desk] is Susan
- "Which boy made cookies?" "It was Jack!" -> [The boy who made the cookies] was Jack
- "Which artist painted it?" "It was her" -> [The artist who painted it] was her
- "Who rang the doorbell?" "That was Peter" -> [The person who rang the doorbell] was Peter
- "Who is the actor that played an action hero" "It is none other than Keanu Reeves" -> [The actor that played an action hero] is Keanu Reeves

We can also use a personal pronoun "He", "She", or "They"(neuter) but this is used when 1) We are referring to a specific person and 2) the answer itself cannot be replaced by a personal pronoun

Can swap:

- "Who is that?" -- "That's my mom" or "She is my mom"-> [This person] is my mom
- "Who is that?" -- "That is my teacher" or "He is my teacher" -> [That person] is my teacher

Can't swap:

- "Who is the manager?" -- "Its Susan"/"Susan is" -> [The manager] is Susan (can be replaced by "her" + indication) -> "It's her"/"She is"
- "Who made the cookies?" -- "It was Jack!"/"Jack did" -> [The cookie baker] was Jack (can be replaced by "him" + indication) -> "It was him"/ "He did"
- "Who rang the doorbell?" -- "It was Peter" -> [The doorbell ringer] was Peter
- "It is none other than Keanu Reeves" -> [The actor] is Keanu Reeves